# Facebook permissions - login flow

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am facebook development newbie and have problems with understanding login flow.

What I want to achieve:

- I need access app user's pictures from the album created by the
  application (preferably also when users are offline).
  I run through facebook samples and stackoverflow questions and what I managed to do is:
  I use facebook authentication with user_photos scope as follows:

however the script retrieving list of albums gets an "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." error.

So I added:
        
            Grant Permissions to Allow access to Photos and Albums

The scope is exactly the same, so I don't understand why after clicking that button retrieving the albums works. 
The problem is that after refreshing the page, app recognizes that I'm a user who uses the app, but the albums are not accessible again.

How can I make app to get the permission to access pictures permanently? 
I suppose it should be possible to access them also when the user is offline (if the album is public)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that script accessing data was loaded faster than the user was verified by facebook. It worked with a button just because clicking a button gave application needed time buffor.